# How to get the httppost filename on the php server

Tags: php

I used FileEntity httppost to post a file to a php apache server，but I do not want to change the name of the file.

How can I get the name of the file from the server using php? I have already get the file:
     $filename='test.zip';//自定义的名字
      file_get_contents('php://input');
     file_put_contents($filename,$data);

Answer (score 1):

HTML (test.html):

```
<!-- Make sure you have enctype and a name on your file input -->
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="test" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP (test.php):

```
// Since we've set our file input to name 'test' and 
// we've posted form-data, we can use $_FILES

print_r( $_FILES['test'] );
```

---

Just use [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

```
Array
(
    [name] => test.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/pasd41l3FmFr
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 15476
)
```

Comment: the result is null. I want to receive this file through move_uploaded_file($_FILES[""]["tmp_name"],$upload_file). but I don't know how to set the $_FILES[""]["tmp_name"]'s first region.

Comment: If using UrlEncodedFormEntity or MultipartEntity in the client ,It is easy to find the string to set the $_FILES[""]["tmp_name"]'s first region.

Comment: It seems like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. I'll edit my answer with a very brief tutorial. You should google for more in-depth information.

Comment: you mean I should use XXX/test.html as the url in the client? I tried this <?php print_r( $_FILES['test'] ); print "nihaoniabah"; ?>nothing is returned in the client

Answer (score 0):

[glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) — Find pathnames matching a pattern

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    print $filename. "\n";
}
```

Comment: In which way does this answer the question?

Comment: I haven't found the filename of the file be upload from client to web server. It seems that using httppost FileEntity to upload file can only upload data in the file. thanks anyway.

Comment: I decided to use  $filename=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())  to name the file uploaded.